# Can I use tinkerkit hall sensor as compass

Tags: arduino

I'm using Tinkerkit shield in combination with an Arduino standard board.
I need a simple compass sensor in order to determine the direction (I don't need a great precision), unluckily similar sensor that works "out of the box" with Tinkerkit does not exist.
Can I use the standard Tinkerkit hall sensor (http://www.tinkerkit.com/hall/) as a compass? If not, can you suggest me how to connect a standard Arduino compass in Tinkerkit?

Thanks

UPDATE
The hall sensor does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure the hall sensor is sensitive enough to be a compass. If you have it, give it a try.

If it doesn't work, you'll need something else. Do you want a compass because your application needs to know the North or do you just need to sense orientation/angular speed? For the first you need a magnetometer, something like that: [Compass Link](http://www.dfrobot.com/index.php?route=product/product&filter_name=compass&product_id=154) 
They give good code examples on how to use it but it won't be as straight as Tinkerkit.
For the second, you can use this: [6DOF IMU](http://www.dfrobot.com/index.php?route=product/product&filter_name=DOF&product_id=788)
I'm using it myself and it's pretty good! You just need to use the [FreeSixIMU library](http://bildr.org/?s=6DOF) from bildr.org to get it to work.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: +1 on the 6352 magnetic compass IC. Very popular among hobbyists so there is a lot of support for it.

Comment: Thanks ladislas, I've tried the hall sensor but it doesn't work... I'll try 6DOF IMU as you suggested

Comment: @Griffosx you're welcome! :) Do not hesitate to get back to us if you've got any questions regarding the library. I also forgot to point out that the shield better works with the Uno or Mega R3. If you have a R2, you need two more wires, but its works well as well!

Comment: @ladislas: it seemed to work pretty well, but I discovered that with this shield there is the gimbal-lock problem. You can see here in action at the end of [this video](https://vimeo.com/75144307). Have you experienced/solved this problem? Thanks a lot

Comment: @ladislas: I resolved! The problem was how I rendered the image, not inside the shield...